# Row and Cells Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I'm having some trouble getting table rows and cells to add onto an existing table and I'm unsure why.

EDIT: What I am trying to achieve is on button click three more rows to be added to the existing table. The extra table rows on button click are not being added to the table.

Using ASP and C#, below is my code, could someone point me in the right direction of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

ASP

```
        <asp:Table ID="tbleEquipment" runat="server">
        <asp:TableHeaderRow runat="server">
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>Sure Shot</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>Body Moving</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>Paul Revere</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>Brass Monkey</asp:TableHeaderCell>
        </asp:TableHeaderRow>
        <asp:TableRow runat="server">
            <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="ET1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="D1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="F1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="P1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow runat="server">
            <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><asp:Button ID="btnAddEquipment" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAddEquipment_Click"></asp:Button></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><asp:Button ID="btnRmvEquipment" runat="server"></asp:Button></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
```

C# Code behind

```
        protected void btnAddEquipment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tbleEquipment.Visible = true;
        btnAddEquipment.Visible = true;


        for (int c = 0; c < 4; c ++)
        {
            TableRow tr1 = new TableRow();
            for (int cc = 0; cc < 4; cc ++)
            {
                TableCell tc1 = new TableCell();
                tr1.Cells.Add(tc1);
            }
            tbleEquipment.Rows.Add(tr1);
        }    
    }
```

Comment: "trouble getting table rows and cells to add onto an existing table" - can you please elaborate . The problem is like the table is geting generated and not able to add it to the existing one / some kind of style issue / you are not getting the tr's itself.

Comment: Apologies, have edited the description - yes, the issue is the table rows are not being added on click, the page reloads and throws no errors but no end result.

Comment: seems like a post-back issue, can you check ispostback?

Comment: The button is causing postback - did a simple label to changed text dependent on whether a postback occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you not set anythings in TabelCell

Try just for check like this then you understand

```
    for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
    {
        TableRow tr1 = new TableRow();
        for (int cc = 0; cc < 4; cc++)
        {
            TableCell tc1 = new TableCell();
            tc1.Text = "|empty Cell|";
            tr1.Cells.Add(tc1);
        }
        tbleEquipment.Rows.Add(tr1);
    }
```

And if you ADD Textbox in that cell then try this way

```
     for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
     {
        TableRow tr1 = new TableRow();
        for (int cc = 0; cc < 4; cc++)
        {
            TableCell tc1 = new TableCell();
            TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
            tb1.ID = "txtTextBox" + cc.ToString();
            tc1.Controls.Add(tb1);
            tr1.Cells.Add(tc1);
        }
        tbleEquipment.Rows.Add(tr1);
     }
```

Comment: Second answer's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
   tbleEquipment.Rows.Add();
}
```